# Laravel + AJAX JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Boa noite,

Estou aprendendo Laravel e preciso atualizar uma div a cada 10 segundos.

Tenho uma rota que ao ser chamada faz uma consulta ao banco de dados. Essa rota retorna a view Dashboard.

Rota:

```
Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@buscarMmDia')->name('buscarMmDia');
```

Na view ele processa o select e mostra na tela:

```
<?php foreach ($buscarMmDia as $p): ?>

        <div class="col s12 m3" id ="frase">
            <div class="card-panel blue">
                <div class="card-content center">
                    <img src="img/weather-rainy2.png">
                    <h5 class="white-text lighten-4">                         
                     <?= $p->mm ?>
                    </h5>
                    <p class="white-text lighten-4">Acumulados hoje.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php  endforeach ?>
```

Controller:

```
 public function buscarMmDia(){

     $buscarMmDia = DB::table('data_collect')

        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as mm'))
        ->whereBetween('date_hour_col',array('2018-11-02 00:00:00','2018-11-02 23:59:59'))
        ->get();     


    return view('dashboard')->with('buscarMmDia', $buscarMmDia);
```

Preciso que essa div seja atualizada a cada 10 segundos. Ou seja faça o select novamente a cada 10 segundos.

Qual é o jeito correto de fazer isso ?

Comment: Atualizar se houver alterações na base, precisa talvez trabalhar com ouro tipo de técnico

Comment: Use o setInterval ou setTimeout pra acessar a rota a cada 10 segundos e recuperar os dados... Com jquery tu atualiza.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver chamando o controller a cada 5 segundos:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
  $('#buscaMmDia').load('{{ action('DashboardController@buscarMmDiaAtualiza') }}');
  }, 5000);
  });
</script>
```